# How about website suggestion based on something such as tags?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, site-recommendation

Sometimes I don't know which Stack Exchange website is suitable for my question. For example, in the past, I had a question about anonymousness of VPN. I asked this question on Network Engineering. But guys told me that is an off-topic question. Finally I found it is suitable for Information Security and got a good answer there.

So I'm wondering if Stack Exchange could add a function to provide suggestion about suitable website based on some information. I guess the easiest one is tag. If I add "networking" and "anonymous" tags, it could suggest me to ask this question on Information Security.

Comment: That's not how it works. If I talk about bugs, should I go to Stack Overflow or Gardening? Automated site recommendation based on keywords is *hard* and error-prone.

Comment: It seems downvoting is common in META. Why? Is this a bad-formatted question?

Comment: @Mast That's true. It is difficult. I've done some recommendation systems in the past so I understand it. But recommendation is just recommendation, it doesn't mean you should go to recommended site, but just provide some information about "Oh, there is a possible website which you may not even know." As there are hundreds of stackexchange websites, recommendation system could even provides several suggestions(for example, five possible ones).

Comment: That would make it even worse. Do you know how many false recommendations users are already posting on multiple sites to (other) multiple sites? If a bot comes in to do another half assed job about it, that's just making the mess worse.

Comment: @Mast What do you mean current "false recommendations users"? Who gives these recommendations? I've not noticed.

Comment: @Sraw Votong on meta is different - downvoting means not agreeing with your proposal, most likely.

Comment: Strangely enough searching for [`[anonymous] [networking]`](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Banonymous%5D+%5Bnetworking%5D) doesn't render any results for the site Information Security...

Comment: @rene but [`[anonymous] [vpn]`](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Banonymous%5D+%5Bvpn%5D) does. (Single result, [much more](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=anonymous+vpn) as plain text search.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I only wanted to *proof* that their suggested tags didn't give a result.

Comment: @rene that's nitpicking. But yeah, still good point. :)

Comment: @Chris Thank you, that makes sense.

Comment: @gnat For me, I don't fully agree with that this is a duplicate. "recommendation based on tag" is just an example used to explain. I believe the developers of SE can do it much better than me. And I don't have to provide a full solution to suggest a proposal right?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know whether something is on-topic on a certain site or not, take a look at their help center:

`https://example.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic`

Works for every SE site.

If you don't know what sites there are, you can take a look at the [overview](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

As I already said in the comments, implementing automated recommendations based on keywords is hard. It's very, very error-prone and will likely create more trouble than it solves. Heck, I'll guarantee you it will.

So, please, no.

Comment: Not relevant for this question. The issue here is that the person doesn't know which site to look at, and since there are over 150, it's really not trivial to find the proper site.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's not trivial. Regardless of how you go about it. But the proposal of the question doesn't improve the situation. Which is noted in the last paragraph.